# Share ListView content in kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

my application that displays the content of firebase databases in ListView .
I want Share all content the ListView in Social Media
I need help from you on the topic of publishing the content of a ListView . Thank you

```
        employeeList = mutableListOf()
        listview = findViewById(R.id.listview1)
        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("rrrdb")

        ref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            }

            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()){
                    employeeList.clear()
                    for (e in snapshot.children){
                        val employee = e.getValue(Employees::class.java)
                        employeeList.add(employee!!)
                        Collections.reverse(employeeList)
                    }
                    val adapter = EmployeeAdapter(this@EmployeesData,R.layout.employees,employeeList)
                    listview.adapter = adapter


                }


            }

        })

        








    }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use Android ShareSheet

```
val sendIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
    action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, employeeList.toString())
    type = "text/plain"
}

val shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null)
startActivity(shareIntent)
```

read more here: https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send